# What could possibly explain this minor data difference from my bank?

Tags: banking, bank-account, online-banking, historical-data, transaction

Half a year ago, I logged into my bank's website and fetched all transaction records for my account as far back as it allowed me, which meant down to the first day of 2009. Saved as CSV file.

For reasons, I repeated this procedure yesterday, and then compared the new CSV file to the old one with WinMerge. Naturally, there had been new items in the top, but there was also a line far, far down which showed a diff!

When I checked it out, it turns out that there was suddenly a **new line** from 2014 where I had bought food in my usual supermarket using my bank card. I verified that this line is just not there in the first CSV file. Only in the second CSV file.

It's not that it's in a different order or anything. The both files are otherwise exactly identical, line by line.

And since it's from 2014, it can't be explained by it being "pending" or something, which they often are, but not for EIGHT YEARS!

I'm going to repeat this procedure in another half a year, just to see what else pops up that they are hiding from me. This really puzzles me and I cannot think of any logical explanation.

Every time I ask them about anything like this, which suggests that something is weird about their system, they just ignore me. That's why I ask here.

Comment: Have the balances changed? Could be a bug somewhere in their exporting system.

Comment: Which country are you in?

Comment: Only your bank can explain this.

Comment: "Every time I ask them about anything like this, which suggests that something is weird about their system, they just ignore me."  Time for a different bank.

Comment: It's a software defect.